# Selecting random array elements and placing into another

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, random

I have an array of strings and require just 4 of these (randomly) to be placed into another array.

```
var a = ["Orange", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Black", "White", "Brown", "Green"];
var b = [];
function selectColours(){
    var toRandomise = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    b.push(toRandomise);
}
console.log(b);
```

My problem is that the Console shows nothing appearing.

Comment: Are you calling `selectColours()`?

Comment: This way you can't get any further than "Blue". Replace `a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]`with `a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need add random value 4 times so you can use for loop

```js
var a = ["Orange", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Black", "White", "Brown", "Green"];
var b = [];

function selectColours() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var toRandomise = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];
    b.push(toRandomise);
  }
}

selectColours()
console.log(b);
```

You can also use recursion.

```js
var a = ["Orange", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Black", "White", "Brown", "Green"];
var b = [], count = 0;


function selectColours() {
  if (count == 4) return true;
  b.push(a[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
  count++;
  selectColours();
}

selectColours()
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you're not really running the function you created. Simply declaring it.

Just write `selectColors();` right before the `console.log`

Comment: Doing this only shows one random string, not the 4 that I require to e stored in the array.

Comment: If you want four strings, rather than one you should put it in a loop. Right now you're just getting a random number between 0 and 3. Also note, that if you don't want results to be duplicated (Having two "Red"s for instance) you need to remove the elements.

Comment: I see where I am going wrong now and a loop has solved it, thankyou.